# Howto fetch additonal remote git branch in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to do the following in jenkins:

1. Checkout/clone my git repostiory in branch1
2. Fetch branch2 (which is ahead of branch1)
3. Get all commiting users between branch1 and branch2

I am using a pipeline.

So I do the checkout with:

```
git branch: 'branch1', credentialsId: 'XXX', url: 'XXX'
```

Now, I want to additionaly fetch 'branch2', I tried:

```
sh 'git fetch origin branch2:branch2'
```

But that fails because of missing credentials.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git credential helper, coupled with the credentials plugin.
Git credential doco: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials
Credentials plugin: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'git', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
    try {
        sh("git config credential.username ${env.GIT_USERNAME}")
        sh("git config credential.helper '!f() { echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; }; f'")
        sh("GIT_ASKPASS=true git fetch origin branch2:branch2")
    } catch (err) {
        println err
        error "ERROR: Failed to fetch changes"
    } finally {
        sh("git config --unset credential.username")
        sh("git config --unset credential.helper")
    }
}
```